# Why is the "forward engineering" feature not working on mySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

### Forward engineering : Problems with transfering data from an EER model to the SQL editor.

I am new to databases development and SQL. It seems like the **forward engineering** feature in **My SQL Workbench** is not working properly.  I am able to edit or add  fields in different tables in the **EER-Model**  but when I run the **forward engineering,** the changes, I had made in all the tables, don't show up in the *SQL editor*.

I installed **MySQL Workbench** software and I configured it to run on a live server .I created an **EER-diagram** and I can edit and modify the schema properly ,create relationships, add new tables.

When i run the **forward engineering** feature , it seems to run without any problems, there are not any ***ERROR*** prompts or warnings and at the ending of  the procedure there is a prompt saying : "Forward engineering completed Successfully!". The message log window appears to be right and I can't identify where the problem comes from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When the FE wizards says all went fine then it's very likely that all went fine :-) In which _SQL Editor_ do you look to see the results? If you mean the SQL IDE then keep in mind that it doesn't automatically refresh tables etc. There is a refresh button at the top of the schema tree that you can use (or the context menu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's some kind of bug on the version of MySQL so instead of choosing the option 'Database->ForwardEngineer' there is a workaround

'Database-->SynchroniseModel' this should show all your changes in SQL Editor

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

go to edit and then preferences then modeling->MySQL and then type 5.7.9 in the Default Target MySQL version
forward engineering don't work sometimes because of mismatch version